# Cambiar tamaño tabs de materialize segun el tamaño la cantidad de elementos <li> agregados

Tags: css, materialize

Tengo este codigo html:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs ">
  <li class="tab" title="¿Cómo ingresar?"><a class="active" href="#swipe-1">Ingreso</a></li>
  <li class="tab" title="¿Olvidó su contraseña?"><a href="#swipe-2">Recuperar contraseña</a></li>
  <li class="tab" title="¿Cómo crear solicitudes?"><a href="#swipe-3">Crear solicitud</a></li>
  <li class="tab" title="¿Cómo revisar las solicitudes creadas por mi?"><a href="#swipe-4">Revisar solicitudes</a></li>
  <li class="tab" title="¿Cómo responder a mis solicitudes?"><a href="#swipe-5">Responder solicitudes</a></li>
  <li class="tab" title="Mi perfil"><a href="#swipe-6">Perfil</a></li>
  <li class="tab" title="Notificaciones"><a href="#swipe-7">Notificaciones</a></li>
  <li class="tab" title="Sugerencias"><a href="#swipe-8">Sugerencias</a></li>
  <li class="tab" title="Desloguearse"><a href="#swipe-9">Salir</a></li>
</ul>
```

Cuando no tengo muchos elementos agregados se muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, cuando quiero agregar más elementos, no se muestra correctamente los demás:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué no se muestra correctamente? ¿Cómo quieres que se vea? Lo que está haciendo es dar el mismo espacio a cada elemento y si no entra el texto lo recorta, lo hace bien, otra cosa es que tu no quieras eso

Comment: precisamente eso es lo que no quiero, quiero que no me corte el texto @blonfu

Comment: Habría que ver los estilos que tienes. A mi con tu html y los estilos de materialize no me recorta los textos sino que pone un scroll al no caber todas las pestañas

Comment: @blonfu edito la pregunta en pocos segundos

Comment: Vale, con esa versión que estás usando lo veo igual que tú, pero ¿cómo quieres que se muestre?

Comment: que no se vea cortado el texto desde el segundo campo, ampliar los campos que se ven incompletos asi poder ver su nombre completamente

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes solucionar cambiando la versión de tu archivo .css a la versión `1.0.0` (la misma que usas para el archivo js). De este modo no se te va a cortar el texto. Lo que si, se te va a agregar una barra de scroll en el caso de no entrar todas las pestañas en la pantalla.  Espero que te sirva, Saludos!

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#tabs-swipe-demo').tabs();
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


  <ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs row">
    <li class="tab col s4" title="¿Cómo ingresar?"><a class="active" href="#swipe-1">Ingreso</a></li>
    <li class="tab" title="¿Olvidó su contraseña?"><a href="#swipe-2">Recuperar contraseña</a></li>
    <li class="tab" title="¿Cómo crear solicitudes?"><a href="#swipe-3">Crear solicitud</a></li>
    <li class="tab" title="¿Cómo revisar las solicitudes creadas por mi?"><a href="#swipe-4">Revisar solicitudes</a></li>
    <li class="tab" title="¿Cómo responder a mis solicitudes?"><a href="#swipe-5">Responder solicitudes</a></li>
    <li class="tab" title="Mi perfil"><a href="#swipe-6">Perfil</a></li>
    <li class="tab" title="Notificaciones"><a href="#swipe-7">Notificaciones</a></li>
    <li class="tab" title="Sugerencias"><a href="#swipe-8">Sugerencias</a></li>
    <li class="tab" title="Desloguearse"><a href="#swipe-9">Salir</a></li>
    
    
  </ul>
```